# "namespace is undefined" problem when using jsTestDriver, Idea 9 and testing 3 test cases. Sometimes it just outright hangs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, namespaces, js-test-driver

I just started using jsTestDriver and I really like it, but all of a sudden, I just started getting a very weird error and I'm not sure what the heck I did to create it. Actually, if I try and run a basic Greeter test, the same problem happens.

Here's an example of one of my javascript files/classes under test:

```
myapp = myapp || {};

myapp.Module = function() {
    ...
};
```

All of the classes follow this pattern.

My test classes generally look like this (I'll give a really simple one):

```
ModuleTest = TestCase("ModuleTest");

ModuleTest.prototype.testInit = function() {
    var module = new myapp.Module(); // <---- it bombs here, on every test!

    assertFalse(module.isStarted);

    module.init();

    assertTrue(module.isStarted);
};
```

It bombs when it gets to "new myapp.Module()". Here is the error message that is given about 30 times for all my tests:

```
myapp is not defined
/src/test/webapp/js/ModuleTest.js:4
```

Here is my configuration file:

```
server: http://localhost:9876

load:
  - src/main/webapp/js/jquery/*.js
  - src/main/webapp/js/*.js
  - src/test/webapp/js/*.js
```

Does anyone have any idea what the heck is wrong? Sometimes when I run all the tests in IDEA, my IDE just hangs altogether or takes like many minutes for jsTestDriver to finally report the above results...

:(

Comment: What does myapp.Module = function () { ... } look like? I had this _exact_ problem just now and it was because I was referring to Module without 'myapp.' within the constructor function.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue after I moved to v.1.3.1. In my case the problem was with file encoding. I use Visual Studio for the development, it adds [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) (3 extra bytes) in the beginning of the file. It's possible to see these bytes in Far manager. If you use VS try to save the file as the following: "File->Advanced save options->" Encoding: Unicode (UTF-8 **without signature**) - Codepage 65001.
It should fix your problem.